# 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: command, flutter

I think I added the path to environment variables and I restarted my PC too, but the "flutter" cmd is not working. Please help me out. I am using windows 10(64 bit) and getting the error

> 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Check if the PATH actually contains the path you added. run `echo %PATH%`

Answer (score 71):

To use the flutter commands in any IDE in windows you need to add the flutter SDK to the windows environements. To do so just follow the simple steps below:

1. Right click on the computer icon in desktop (make sure its not a shortcut) and select **properties**.

[image]

On the left side of the new opened window click on **Advanced system settings**.[image]

2. Now in the system properties window that opens select **Environment Variables**.[image]
3. In the new window **double click** on **path** to open a new window.

[image]

4. In the new window opened click on **New** and paste the path of the **bin** folder located in the flutter sdk folder. For example my path is this: `D:\FlutterSDK\flutter\bin`

**Note:** It doesn't matter where you want to place the flutter SDK, just copy and paste the path of the bin folder here.

[image]

5. Click OK, OK, OK.

Now you're all set. Try restarting the IDE or even better restart the PC.

Comment: This worked for me. Restarting the IDE is enough. No need to restart PC.

Comment: This worked on my PC too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is how you do it

Comment: Restarting PC Works :)

Comment: do not need to restart, logoff and login :)

Answer (score 8):

Add the path till ...\flutter\bin directory to your system variables.
This will help.

Comment: Changed the path, now resolved working properly. Thankyou

Comment: can you be more specific please, where have you changed your path?

Comment: @JagrajSingh in environment variable? full path of bin folder of flutter SDK..

Comment: @JagrajSingh  Actually In my laptop there is two users. I am working on one User named "TC01" . I have set environment variable successfully ,restart IDE and Laptop also .I able to run command of flutter from C/flutter/flutter_console.bat file but not able to run command from Android Studio's terminal.

Comment: I had this same issue a few days before, The AS terminal wasn't picking env variables from its settings. So what I did was, change the env variables for the system and then close the AS and open it again (NOT Restarted) and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I had some trouble with this, and would like to share what I found. I used the "new" button in the environment variables (I was in the path edit screen), and I added

E:\Flutter_for_web\flutter\bin;

However, this did not work, and I had to constantly set the variable locally to get it to work. After a while I dug deeper and ran

echo %PATH%

which shows my path variables. I noticed the ones I added with the "new" button had quotes around them , and an extra ";" after the quote.

The Solution was to add the paths using the "Edit Text" button in the environment variable edit screen. and then re run "echo %PATH%" to make sure those quotes are gone. Restart the terminal and everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another source of this problem, on Windows at least, is if the Flutter folder contains special characters.

The solution is to install Flutter in a path containing only alphanumeric characters (just to be sure). Be sure to update the PATH Environment Variable, as suggested in the other answers.

Turns out I had "C:\flutter=bin=\bin" in my PATH. The "=" in it are a construct I commonly use to get a folder to 1) list before regular folders, and 2) to mark it up as special. The "=" however ends up tripping up the flutter.bat batch-file (executed by the flutter command on Windows). Renaming it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you have setup up the path in the User Variable under the Path of "../flutter/bin" full path and it is still not able to detect then the chances are that the User Variable is different from user current user. Kindly have a look over it, this might happen if you have installed something like OneDrive.

In that case I found out that it works if you paste the path into the System Variable which is a quick workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am resolving this error using to added both System and User in Environment Variable, you can add this path "c/dev/flutter/bin" to Env Var in both sections.
I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem

After adding to windows environment like @Taba stated

Exit the command line and restart or restart the IDE

Everything should work fine

Answer (score 0):

My problem just solved by closing the command prompt and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to solve this problem by adding the path to your environment variables but still doesn't work.

Check if you are using a Local Account in your Windows 10 machine and not a Administrator Account. If you are not using an administrator account it will not work.

First, login to your machine using the Administrator account and change the user type  of the account that you wish to use in installing flutter to Administrator account.[Create a local user or administrator account in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account-in-windows-20de74e0-ac7f-3502-a866-32915af2a34d)

After that, login again to the windows account that you want to use (that is now a Administrator account too).

Then, add the path of the SDK to the environment variables. You will notice that the content of the environment variables are different.

Then run flutter doctor again.