# Why my VS code terminal is not recognizing the term 'flutter'?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am running a command that is `flutter devices` to check the connected devices, but it is giving the following error:

```
flutter: The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ flutter devices
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException 

flutter devices
```

Comment: You need to add path to the *flutter/bin* folder to your system PATH variable. You can refer to the steps given [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path).

Comment: oh got it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["flutter" is not recognized as an internal and external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636255/flutter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-and-external-command)

Answer (score 7):

After the flutter download, path variable setting and "flutter" enabling activity in VS code, you might forget to restart the already opened VS code. So **restart VS code**

Answer (score 0):

u have to add path variable say C:\Program Files\flutter\bin and after that restart the Visual Code. now u can run the commands on terminal.