# flutter is not recognized as an internal and external command

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to install flutter in windows 8.1 pro
and have set the path in **Environmental Setting** - **C:\src\flutter\bin**

and tried "flutter" in cmd prompt and getting error 
**flutter is not recognized as an internal and external command**

Comment: 1.Did you restart the cmd after you changed the Environmental settings? 2. copy C:\src\flutter\bin to your address bar in windows explorer then run CMD there, then run the `flutter doctor`.

Comment: [this might help](https://androidride.com/how-to-install-flutter-in-android-studio-in-windows/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636255/flutter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

You should edit environment variables for your account. Somebody already asked this question here you can see the answer ['flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636255/flutter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Or use flutter docs and do steps under update your path paragraph https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a new path to flutter\bin file in the **user** environment variable, make your way straight down to the **system** variables list, choose to **edit** the path there and add the **new** file address.