# flutterfire : The term 'flutterfire' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am getting this error when I run "dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli" :

> Activated flutterfire_cli 0.1.1+2. Package flutterfire_cli is
> currently active at version 0.1.1+2. Resolving dependencies... The
> package flutterfire_cli is already activated at newest available
> version. To recompile executables, first-run `dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli`. Installed executable flutterfire.
> Warning: Pub installs executables into
> C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
> You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path"
> environment variable. A web search for "configure windows path" will
> show you how

I have added this to my user path but I am still getting this error.
I checked for solutionsto similar problems which suggested I restart the windows or vs code or terminal - I did all three but it is still not working .
I ran in cmd in that it did not give the warning but when I ran **flutterfire configure** . It gave this error:

> "FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when
> attempting to run a command. COMMAND: firebase --version ERROR: The
> FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also
> be installed, see
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how
> to install it."

running firebase --version gave this error:

> 'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file

This should not be happening as I did connect my app to firebase console.

Comment: have you added the flutterfire executable location to environment variables?

Comment: yes i have it is still not working

Comment: if you have added the path to system variables firebase --version command wouldn't show it as unrecognized command. maybe you have added a wrong path.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is instead of typing
`flutterfire` I use `flutterfire.bat`, e.g. `flutterfire.bat configure`, that way the command works in the git bash with windows.

Comment: Your comment should be framed ! thank you ! worked for me that way

Answer (score 2):

If you have windows 10. Do not use `firebase-tools-instant-win.exe` its a trap!

Add Paths to System Variables. Don't forget to change to your username in `YOU-USER-NAME`

```
C:\Users\YOU-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
C:\Users\YOU-USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Next you can execute anywhere (in `cmd` or `firebase-tools-instant-win.exe`)

```
firebase login
npm install -g firebase-tools
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

Next you open only cmd.exe command promt and go to the root of your project.

```
cd c:\PATH-TO-YOU-PROJECT
flutterfire configure
```

Comment: It work for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **add Flutter SDK path to your system environment**. The error is arising because your **system is not able to find the folder where you have installed Flutter in your system**.

You may refer to the [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636255/flutter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/63766068) for the steps on how to set path for the system environment.

Alternatively, you may also refer to the [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jrmxXtK_0k).

Comment: Yes I had added the flutter sdk to my environment path , I am still getting the error

Comment: you should add firebase path to system environment. this is what is been missing I presume

Comment: I added but it is still showing this error that i have not

Comment: Make sure that you do 'npm install -g firebase-tools' for npm installation in order to make the flutterfire to be recognized. You may refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-windows).

Comment: Did my answer help you in resolving the issue?