# Flutter running with no response after first installation in Windows

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, command

I'm new in flutter and trying to learn about it for the first time.

 I'm following the instruction of flutter documentation in [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows)

When in step to the setting environment, I follow the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63766068/4539582).

After restarting the pc, the next step I must running the command `flutter doctor` in cmd.

In this step, I get stuck because in cmd, `flutter` doesn't response anything.

[image]

I try to execute flutter inside `VSCode` It still stuck with loading.

[image]

I also try to running with android studio, Still the same, I get stuck with loading

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the important thing.

[image]

Just don't put it in the privilege directory.