Flutter command not recognized after installation on Windows 10
I apologize if this is a simple question or if my English is awkward (it’s translated).
I’m trying to set up Flutter on my Windows 10 machine. I downloaded the Flutter SDK as a ZIP, extracted it to C:\flutter, and added C:\flutter\flutter\bin to the PATH in environment variables.
After doing this, I still cannot get flutter --version to work in the command prompt. It says: 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
Restarting my computer.
Running the command prompt as administrator.
Verifying that C:\flutter\flutter\bin is properly in the PATH.
When I directly run the command like this from the command prompt: C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter --version It seems to work.
I'm really exhausted from trying everything I can think of, but it still won’t recognize flutter in a normal command prompt.
Does anyone have an idea what I might be missing or doing wrong?
Thank you so much in advance!

You should follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636255/flutter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command Did you really add it to the PATH or you did like the third reply and click on "new"?

What I think you need to check did you give path to envirmental variable to 
I think you to give path to both envirment variables. System and you account variables also.

Please refrain from manually installing the Flutter SDK, especially if you're new to the Flutter framework.
To understand first on how to install it properly, kindly visit this website. If you properly follow the steps and procedure of how to install Flutter on your machine, you can also develop a multi-platform project using it.
I hope it helps!
